# How to Create 3 Sides Flip Effects

Tags: jquery, css

Can you please let me know how I can create a 3 sides flip effect

```
<div class="flip"> 
     <div class="card"> 
            <div class="face one"> 
                One
            </div> 
            <div class="face two"> 
                Two
            </div> 
             <div class="face three"> 
                Three
            </div> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

I have tried some [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/qygdr018/) but it is skipping the second face from one to three.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `transform: rotatex(90deg);` to class `.two`
But it's really glitched (at least in FF) so you may need to add `translate3d()` in your `transform` as well :

```
.two {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(90deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 2em);
    transform: rotatex(90deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 2em);
```

```js
    $('.flip').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('flipped');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
.face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.one {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.two {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(90deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 2em);
    transform: rotatex(90deg) translate3d(0, 50%, 2em);
    background: white;
    color: black;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
}
.three {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: green;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face one">One</div>
        <div class="face two">Two</div>
        <div class="face three">Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kaiido and Thanks for the code but there are some issues here. As you can see the slide `two` is over lapping on the top!. Can you please take a Look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/qygdr018/) and let me know how to fix this thing? Thanks